# How do I pull in multiple pdfs into pdf_convert using r and pdftools package?

Tags: r, pdf, data-munging

How do I import multiple pdf files into the `pdf_convert` command of the `pdftools` package?

I have a directory that with multiple pdf files.  I'm using the `pdftools` package with the `pdf_convert` command to render jpegs from the pdf document.  However, there is no `pattern` command to set a pattern to the documents.

I've tried:

```
for(i in length(dir(folder))){
   pdf_convert("C:/folder/*.pdf", format = "jpeg")
}
```

However that throws an error that says:

`Error in normaizePath(path.expand(path), winslash, mustWork) :`
`path[1]="C:/folder/*.pdf: The filename, director name, or volume label syntax is incorrect`

When I don't use the `*.pdf` and instead use the actual file name, it works.

How do I get the command to read multiple files?

I'm sorry I don't have a reproducible example.  I'm not sure how I would post a directory with multiple pdf files and access to it on SO.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This will do the trick and no need for a loop.

```
library(pdftools)

directory <- "C:/folder"
file.list <- paste(directory, "/",list.files(directory, pattern = "*.pdf"), sep = "")

lapply(file.list, FUN = function(files) {
  pdf_convert(files, format = "jpeg")
})
```

Comment: Worked perfectly!  Thank you.

Comment: @ phiver: great answer! can you please take a look at this related question if you have time? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68607194/r-error-names-attribute-1-must-be-the-same-length-as-the-vector-0 thank you!