# R Error: 'names' attribute [1] must be the same length as the vector [0]

Tags: r, pdf, text, import, tesseract

I have a number of pdf files (these are "scanned") in a folder (`"C:/Users/Documents/files_i_want"`). The PDF's files look like this:
https://jeroen.github.io/images/ocrscan.pdf

All the pdf files have different names. I am trying to import them all into R at the same time, by using the following command: `pdftools::pdf_convert`

```
library(pdftools) 
    library(tesseract)

#Get the path of filenames

filenames <- list.files("C:/Users/Documents/files_i_want", full.names = TRUE)

#Read them in a list

list_data <- lapply(filenames,  pdftools::pdf_convert)

#Name them as per your choice (df_1, df_2 etc)

names(list_data) <- paste('df', seq_along(filenames), sep = '_')

#Create objects in global environment.

list2env(list_data, .GlobalEnv)
```

This returns the following error:

```
Error in names(list_data) <- paste("df", seq_along(filenames), sep = "_") : 
  'names' attribute [1] must be the same length as the vector [0]
```

Does anyone know why this error is being produced?

Thanks

**UPDATE**

I figured out how to upload all the pdf's from the folder:

```
library(pdftools)
library(tesseract)

directory <- "C:/Users/OneDrive/Documents/files_i_want"

file.list <- paste(directory, "/",list.files(directory, pattern = "*.pdf"), sep = "")

b = lapply(file.list, FUN = function(files) {
    pdf_convert(files, format = "jpeg")
})

a = data.frame(file.list)
```

Now, I have to figure out how to apply the following function on each "entry" within the object "a", e.g. "i" represents each "entry" within object "a" (the goal is to create "text_1" and "text_2", e.g. text_1 <- tesseract::ocr(a[1, "file.list"])  )

```
convert_function <- function(i){
text_i <- tesseract::ocr(i)
}
```

Comment: What does `names(list_data)` return? What does `seq_along(filenames)` return?

Comment: @ dcarlson: thank you for your reply!

Comment: > names(list_data) :
NULL

Comment: > seq_along(filenames) :
integer(0)

Comment: I remember a very similar, if not identical question from you from a couple weeks back. Did you repost it or is this one different?

Comment: So it seems your filenames vector is of length 0

Comment: This one is clearly missing a proper reproducible example, as likely there are problems in the `list.files("C:/Users/Documents/files_i_want")` part, which we can not check ourselves

Comment: @ GuedesBF: thank you for your reply! I think had posted a related question a few months ago about mass importing "csv" files.

Comment: So `list_data` has no names and `filenames` is empty. What does `list.files("C:/Users/Documents/files_i_want", full.names = TRUE)` return?

Comment: @GuedesBF : thank you for your reply! I can direct you to a website that contains sample (scanned) PDF's in a similar format. If you download this PDF to your computer, save it into a folder, and then make several copies of this PDF with different names - you can reproduce the example.

Comment: I think no one would usually be that interested in helping anyone so as to actually go after external links etc. You should provide means of reproducing or understanding your issues inside the question whenever possible

Comment: You likely have a wrong path name in list.files...

Comment: @ GuedesBF : thank you for your reply! I have included an example as to how the PDF's look like

Comment: In a next time, please go through the minor details such as typos and minor synthax issues on your own before asking questions, and not while you do it, with contless updates as you go through minimal breakthroughs. HELP VAMPIRES are usually not welcomed in SO.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this code -

```
data <- lapply(sub('pdf$', 'jpeg', file.list),  tesseract::ocr)
names(data) <- paste0('text', seq_along(data))
list2env(data, .GlobalEnv)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I just wrote the same thing in an a "for loop" : for (i in 1:2)
{
    ffile_i =  tesseract::ocr(a[i, "file.list"])
}